# Where can I find the password for the Necromancer Tower?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I finally tracked down the location of the Necromancer Tower, however when I tried to enter it, I was told I needed a password. Where can I find this password? I found one source mentioning it was in Buffalo Pile, however after searching through the entire place, I could not find it. Where is the password hidden?

Comment: Based on your initial source, answer and the new one - maybe the location changes per game :)

Comment: @Alok possibly. i will play through a few characters and see if i can find all the possible spots

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though it varies by playthrough, however 3 locations it is known to appear are,

- in the outhouse in plot 3 of the graveyard in Reboot Hill. When
  searching it (requires stench resistance), I found a sticky note with
  the password written on it.
- In Buffalo Pile, exact location unknown
- Shroomcave, among the bones at the far right of the cave.

Answer (score 1):

Came to this thread to find an answer to your question. None of the answers here are correct, but I stumbled across it about an hour later. It's in the Shroom cave, in a pile of bones right at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're all correct. The password appears in different places every gameplay but these places are where it can be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them:

1. in the shroom cave next to the pile of bones;
2. in the buffalo pile in the trash near the toilet;
3. in the outhouse at reboot hill in plot 3.
4. in the daveyard in the hut

Comment: Sorry to the person that disliked it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: This doesn't add anything that hasn't already been said.

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I'll try to change it when other things pop up. Playing it myself right now! :)

Comment: I added one more that isn't on there :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself in the Buffalo Pile. Trash pile next to one of the toilets